# I cannot get a Start-Job with passed arguments to start

Tags: function, url, powershell, parameters, start-job

I'm trying to use this:

```
$Properties = @((0,100),(20,200))
$URLS = @(("www.google.com","www.yahoo.com"),("www.bing.com","www.msn.com"))

for ($a=0; $a -le 0; $a++)
{
for ($b=0; $b -le 1; $b++)
    {
        Start-Job -name ("Job"+$a+$b) -FilePath "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Voodoo\Voodoo-v2\Jobs\NewJob1-1.ps1" -ArgumentList $a,$b,$Properties,$URLS
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}
```

To run this:

```
param $c $d $Prop $U

function OpenBrowserWindow([int]$top,[int]$left)
    {
        $date = get-date
        $Global:ie = new-object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"  
        $ie.visible = $true  
        $ie.Top = $top
        $ie.Left = $left
        #$ie.FullScreen = $true
    }

function URL($URL1,$URL2)
    {     
        $ie.navigate($URL1) 
        start-sleep -s 5
        $ie.navigate($URL2)
        start-sleep -s 5
    }

OpenBrowserWindow $Prop[$c][$d] $Prop[$c][1];

do
{
    URL $U[$c][$d] $U[$c][1];
}
until ($date.year -ieq 2020)
```

But I keep getting:

> ```
> Start-Job : Missing ')' in function parameter list.
> At C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Voodoo\Homer\Tester22.ps1:9 char:13
> +             Start-Job <<<<  -name ("Job"+$a+$b) -FilePath "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Voodoo\Voodoo-v2\Jobs\NewJob1-1.ps1" -ArgumentList $a,$b,$Properties,$URLS
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [Start->Job], ParseException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartJobCommand
> ```

I've checked this thing over and over again, but can't seem to find where I am missing the ')'

If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You use invalid syntax. Try this `param ($c, $d, $Prop, $U)` instead at first.

Comment: And you can simplify this parameter `("Job"+$a+$b)` to `"Job$a$b"` or perhaps the more readable `"Job-$a-$b"`. You know, just to get rid of some unnecessary parens.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the first line of the `ps1`. the parameters must be enclosed in a parenthesis.

```
param( $c $d $Prop $U)

function OpenBrowserWindow([int]$top,[int]$left)
    {
        $date = get-date
        $Global:ie = new-object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"  
        $ie.visible = $true  
        $ie.Top = $top
        $ie.Left = $left
        #$ie.FullScreen = $true
    }

function URL($URL1,$URL2)
    {     
        $ie.navigate($URL1) 
        start-sleep -s 5
        $ie.navigate($URL2)
        start-sleep -s 5
    }

OpenBrowserWindow $Prop[$c][$d] $Prop[$c][1];

do
{
    URL $U[$c][$d] $U[$c][1];
}
until ($date.year -ieq 2020)
```